# Xcode not refreshing code so errors still display

Tags: xcode

I was wondering if there is a refresh short cut for refreshing code because there has been many times I'm fixing a "error" and the code doesn't refresh so i don't if i fixed it and the error still remains but the problem is fixed.

Comment: Just build, command-b

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Coding without live issues? No thanks!

This problem appeared after renaming my Xcode project and some combination of these steps fixed it for me:

1. Uncheck / recheck "Show live issues" under File > Project settings > General
2. Clean build folder (open the Product menu and hold the "option" key)
3. Delete derived data ([How to delete derived data in Xcode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8))
4. Restart Xcode

Comment: Thank you! This should be the accepted answer! Of course I know that **build** will remove the phantom errors but that is not a valid alternative for working live checker what is an important part of almost every modern IDE.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common occurrence in Xcode.
You can simply press `cmd`+`b` to **build** the project. That will remove any errors.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: this is workaround; not a solution for live issue checker not working properly.

Comment: Why thanks for the downvote, @davis. The fact that it does not work for you does not mean it doesn't work for everyone.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth it is not about whether your workaround works or not. Look at it this way - does your solution fix the broken live issue checker?

Comment: Yes, for me, and at least one other person, it did.